# specify mount option in /etc/fstab (mode=1777)

Tags: filesystems, mount, fstab, tmp

I have following line in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/tmp /tmp    ext4    noexec,nodev,nosuid,mode=1777    0    0
```

When I try to mount `/tmp`, I get following error in `dmesg`:

```
 EXT4-fs (dm-1): Unrecognized mount option "mode=1777" or missing value
```

How can I specify that `/tmp` will have permissions `1777` ? I am recreating (formatting) the filesystem on `/dev/mapper/tmp` every time I boot, so the permissions do not survive reboot.

From what I googled, `mode=1777` should do the job. But it does not work for me.

## UPDATE:

To make the situation more illustrative, here is the script that I am using:

```
cryptsetup --key-file /dev/urandom create tmp /dev/sda2

mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/tmp > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This script is run during the boot sequence, after `checkroot`. Then, later when `bootall` wants to mount `/tmp`, it sees the entry in fstab and mounts `/dev/mapper/tmp` as `/tmp`.

Since I am creating the `LUKS` device during every boot, I have to format the partition every time as well. Contrary to what some people have commented here, the permissions **DO NOT** survive the formatting. Obviously.

Comment: `mode=...` is not a valid mount option for `ext4` (see `man mount > FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS` and [ext4-specific mount options](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt)). You usually `mount -options /dev/whatever /tmp` then `chmod 1777 /tmp`.

Comment: @don_crissti - but I don't mount `/tmp` manually. I have an entry in `/etc/fstab` and it gets mounted automatically by some script in `/etc/init.d/`.

Comment: What command do you use to format the filesystem and is it contained in a shell script somewhere?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick - please see my update

Comment: After the mkfs line in your script, can you add `mount /dev/mapper/tmp /mnt;chmod 1777 /mnt/.;umount /dev/mapper/tmp` ?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick - that would work, but it looks very "ugly". If I find no better solution, I will add the chmod command into `/etc/rc.local`, so that the permissions are changed after `/tmp` has been mounted.

Answer (score 0):

With a `systemd` enabled system you can use `tmpfiles`. See `man 5 tmpfiles.d` for details.

Create a file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` with this content:

```
d /tmp 1777 root root - -
```

`systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` will take care of your permissions.

Comment: That's actually a good solution! The alternative would be to create a service unit file, but I really like this approach more.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need a bigger `/tmp` than can fit into your free RAM+swap, you might consider using a `tmpfs`-based `/tmp`, which is essentially a RAM-disk, and use the disk space previously allocated for `/tmp` to increase swap space instead.

It will only use as much RAM as needed by the current contents, and will move least recently used contents into swap if RAM is getting low.

You would only need an `/etc/fstab` line like this:

```
tmpfs  /tmp tmpfs rw,mode=1777 0 0
```

The default maximum size limit is 50% of your free RAM. You can use the `size=` option to specify another maximum size, either as percentage of free RAM, or as a number of bytes (with an optional `k`, `m` or `g` suffix for 1024-based kilo/mega/gigabytes).

If you are already using encrypted swap that gets re-encrypted at every reboot, this would give you effectively similarly re-encrypting `/tmp` for free, with a performance boost if you have enough RAM to hold the contents of `/tmp`.

Answer (score -1):

Change the line in `/etc/fstab` to:

`/dev/mapper/tmp /tmp    ext4    noexec,nodev,nosuid    0  0`

Then login and issue:

`chmod 1777 /dev/mapper/tmp`

The next reboot your `/etc/fstab` will suffice as `chmod` is permanent.  You are trying to use an option designed for Windows mounts (fat, ntfs,
etc) in a native Linux filesystem (ext4). Instead, you change the
permissions of the folder with chmod.

See [Suse Forums Post](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/488052-mode-1777-unrecognized-mount-option).

You cannot use mode in `ext4`.  As such, you may need to mount the filesystem you create some other way.  You could create an `ext3` partition somewhere else.

Comment: as I said in my original question, "I am recreating (formatting) the filesystem on /dev/mapper/tmp every time I boot, so the permissions do not survive reboot". I would have to run `chmod 1777 /tmp` every time I reboot.

Comment: @MartinVegter Yes, you have to do that. The ext4 filesystem stores permissions. The permissions of a file on an ext4 filesystem are whatever is stored there.

Comment: @Gilles - what would be the recommended way to change the permissions automatically upon boot? Put the `chmod` command into `/etc/rc.local` ?

Comment: @MartinVegter See my last sentence.  I know you're recreating it.  If you use systemd, [you could write a service](http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html).  Is it necessary that you use `/tmp`?  You could mount it in `/mnt`  IIRC, the mounted filesystem inherits permissions from the mount point...